# Git merge to handle deleted files

Tags: git

I am working on automating git operations using Unix shell scripting, and I need a bit of help on a specific merge operation.

Assume I want to merge two branches - branch A and B
And, I am doing something like this in my script

```
git checkout A; git merge  -X theirs--no-ff --no-commit B
```

There is a file (9.sql) which exists in branch B, however it's deleted in branch A.

When I execute the above command, it says Already up-to-date, but when I do the reverse merging, the file is deleted from branch B.

My question is, even if I use -X theirs, the file from branch B is not added to branch A, which is required.

What should I do?

Comment: The strategy is only used when there is a conflict, if a file has been deleted in one branch, and not modified or deleted in the other, the file will be deleted regardless of whether you use a strategy or not.

Comment: I acknowledge, however these are part of a generic script that handles all merge requirements, even if there are conflicts, and in such cases, we are getting the copy from the branch we are merging(here branch B). But that being said, shouldn't all files from branch B be retained in branch A as because we are using -X theirs strategy? If so, the file 9.sql which exists in branch B must be added to branch A as well which is not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to happen, presumably the file existed in the common ancestor, was never changed on branch B, and was deleted on branch A.

In this case, you don't really want a recursive merge which uses `theirs` as the option to resolve conflicts. That is,

```
git merge -X theirs
```

means use the default recursive strategy with option *theirs*. It's equivalent to

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs
```

What you actually want is to use a different *strategy*, such as:

```
git merge -s theirs
```

which unfortunately doesn't exist.

If you want to pretend a merge happened but really make the tree identical to B, you can do that. If not, I'm not sure what kind if result you expect.

Comment: Yes, I want to fake a merge and make the tree identical to B. How would I do that?

Comment: If you want to make a tree identical to B, then reset the branch there.